# Cmdlet invocation changes-unable to create Virtual Network using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell, powershell-7.0

When I run this: **$frontEndSubnet = New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig -Name frontEndSubnet -AddressPrefix "10.0.1.0/24"**
**[Showing the below error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXZPn.jpg)**
"WARNING: Breaking changes in the cmdlet 'New-AzVirtualNetworkSubnetConfig' :
WARNING:  - Update Property Name

WARNING: Cmdlet invocation changes :
    Old Way : -ResourceId
    New Way : -NatGatewayId
WARNING:  - Update Property Name

WARNING: Cmdlet invocation changes :
    Old Way : -InputObject
    New Way : -NatGateway"

Comment: while i don't know the answer ... i can help slightly. please add the Az Powershell module version. the MSDocs site shows the current version is `3.7.0`. so that may be important info for those who _do_ know something about the subject.

Comment: Have installed Azure CLI version 2.3.1 and powershell core 7.0.0.0

Comment: PLEASE, add that info to your Question so that others can find it easily.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use the cmdlet **Set-AzVirtualNetwork** after your cmd
For your example:
`$frontEndSubnet | Set-AzVirtualNetwork`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/set-azvirtualnetwork?view=azps-4.2.0